# SQL: how to best store many small snippets of varying data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a project for one of my classes where we get a very large dataset consisting of many news articles that have been split up into individual sentences and randomized.  Our job is to basically reassemble all the snippets into the original news articles.  The data we are given has a certain structure that we can use to sort it.

My issue is how to store the data in a database.  I have 2 thoughts:

1) Create a new table for every single news article, and then add the appropriate sentences to that table as they are processed.  Our data is expected to be several GB, so there could possibly be hundreds or thousands of articles.  However, after sorting, there would not need to be as many queries, and the post-processing reassembly of the articles would be fairly straightforward.

2) I could make basically one large table in the DB and use a column as some type of key to distinguish which sentence goes to which article.  However, when I have to stitch the articles back together, this would take a lot of queries and processing to get everything right, not to mention coming up with a valid key scheme.

The project after this one (that will build upon the framework I create now) will use blogs (which can change) as opposed to static news articles.  So, I will have to deal with not only sorting the sentences, but also deleting, changing, or adding new ones dynamically.

In terms of performance, reliability, and maintainability, which option is better?  I am also open to any other better ways of doing this.

Comment: Read this article before you go ahead with designing you new database schema [`Database Normalization Basics`](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider using 3 tables, and do something like the following:

```
Article
-------
(PK) ArticleID


Sentence
--------
(PK) SentenceID


ArticleSentence
---------------
(PK) ArticleSentenceID
(FK) ArticleID
(FK) SentenceID
```

The ArticleSentence table would be used to map sentences to articles, while using many-to-one relationships. Obviously your tables will have more columns as needed, but that is the general idea of relating two tables via a third table.

By doing it this way, you are also giving yourself quite a bit of flexibility in terms of handling the data. Sure, by splitting each article into a separate table it would be easy to get the sentences for that article. But what if you want to relate similar articles? By doing it the way I mentioned, you can also query all articles that have a certain sentence. Keeping the articles and sentences as two separate tables will make your life easier in the end.

Comment: So just to summary, I have a table of articles, a table of sentences, and a table to relate the 2, correct?  Is there a limit to the size of a table? Because I am expecting to have over a million sentences to keep track of.

Comment: @Tim a million rows will be perfectly fine. My company has some tables with nearly a billion records. You should be fine :)